# How to write data in an excel file using python

Tags: python, xls

Im making an API request to pull some articles bodies and ids. I would like to pull them into an excel file where on the first column the id's are displayed and on the next column the corresponding bodies are displayed.

I managed to bring it this far but for some reason the formatting in excel is not right.
There is a lot of data that I'm trying to pull here but I would want to display each one of them in it's separate cell.

Can I specifically ask my script to transpose the data automatically?

```python
import requests
import csv
import unicodedata
import getpass
import xlsxwriter 

url = 'https://.../articles.json'

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('bodies.xlsx') 
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet() 


output_1 = []

output_2 = []


listOf = ([output_1],[output_2])
 

while url:
    user = 'email@email.com'
    pwd = '1234'
    response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd))
    data = response.json()
    for article in data['articles']:
        article_id = article['id']
        body = article['body']
        decode_1 = int(article_id)
        decode_2 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', body)
        output_1.append(decode_1)
        output_1.append(decode_2)

    print(data['next_page'])
    url = 'https://.../articles.json' and data['next_page']

row = 0
col = 0
for output_1, output_2 in (listOf): 
    worksheet.write_row(row, col, output_1) 
    worksheet.write_column(col, col + 1, output_2) 
    col += 1
  
workbook.close()
```

Update:

So basically in my script I'm reading a json that looks something like this

```
"per_page": 30,
"previous_page": null,
"articles": [
        {
            "id": 360239848018,
            "url": "https://.../articles/360239848018.json",
            "html_url": "https://...",
            "author_id": 5201232,
            "body": "<div class....a lot of html" }
```

Comment: For further clarification, could you check and post what `decode_2` looks like?

Comment: I assume because  ```decode_1``` is a int, the script writes a new row for each number(total of 845 rows). In the case of ```decode_2``` it all get's added to 10 rows..spreading over multiple columns (until DD).
I just want to have 2 columns and 845 rows in total.

Comment: Are you using `write_column()` instead of `write_row()`?

Comment: yes I am .. I tried with both... tbh the way it is displayed is not really important.. Im just interested that each id has a body and each body is in one cell

Comment: Could you share a screenshot with what you are seeing? And also the data structure of `decode_2`?

Comment: so basically the first column goes all the way down to row 845 .. the second column.. well you can see how it looks like.
I'm thinking that maybe it has something to do with the encoding?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `pandas`? It has the ability to build a dataframe from json with `pd.read_json()`

Comment: Regarding the screenshot: It looks like the second column is not filled at all, this is just the first column being extended in this particular formatting of the data. It still looks like you are using only one `list` to store IDs **and** the content.

Comment: I started out like this.. but I also started reading about pandas and probably this will be my next approach

Comment: If you can provide me with the URL with the JSON, I could try to get it working with `pandas`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all the data that you are scraping with the code you've shared ends up in `output_1`, while `output_2` is empty.

Since you'd like to have the `article_id` in one column and the content in another column, I would suggest to store the content in `output_2` instead of `output_1`.

Apart from that, you are using `write_row()` on `output_1`. As per [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write) (emphasis mine):

> Write a **row** of data starting from (row, col).

But it sounds like you'd like to write it as a column.

Another thing to keep in mind is that your `listOf` is a tuple containing two lists. Iterating it won't get you far.

With all of the above said, this is what should work:

```python
import csv
import requests
import unicodedata
import xlsxwriter 

url = 'https://.../articles.json'

output_1 = []
output_2 = []

while url:
    user = 'email@email.com'
    pwd = '1234'
    response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd))
    data = response.json()
    for article in data['articles']:
        article_id = article['id']
        body = article['body']
        decode_1 = int(article_id)
        decode_2 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', body)
        output_1.append(decode_1)
        output_2.append(decode_2)
      # ^^^^^^^^
      # This is output_2 now.

    print(data['next_page'])
    url = 'https://.../articles.json' and data['next_page']


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('bodies.xlsx') 
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
col = 0

worksheet.write_column(row, col, output_1)
#         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
#         use write_column instead of write_row
worksheet.write_column(row, col + 1, output_2)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: in my case i'm making an api request that has a limit of 30 per page... in my case the total number of pages are 30. The script reads the json response and if there is a next page it executes the for loop again.
I was wondering if I could write a for loop inside the existing for loop so that I could join these two arrays?

Comment: I realised that missed the `url` update in my answer and I've updated it now. Does this help?

Comment: it looks like it's the same script I wrote... just that you append it to the right array.
So basically I get the id columns right but the body column is not formated right.. it is spread on 10 rows and 20 columns to the right whereas the id column is spread nicely in 845 rows

Comment: It's also using `write_column()` instead of `write_row()`.